# Declaring a long long array with unsigned int size

Tags: c, arrays, unsigned-integer, long-long

I was doing a problem when I encountered a segmentation fault while declaring an array as:

```
long long ways[max+1];
```

where,

```
unsigned int max = findMax(l,T); // l is an unsigned int array and T is an int.
```

and findMax is a function of the type:

```
unsigned int findMax(unsigned int arr[],int size)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How big is `max`? Probably stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A probable reason is that the array is too big for the stack.

Typical stack sizes as of now is 1-16 Mb (could be considerably less in an embedded system). If `long long` is 8 bytes it would mean that allocating one array of more than 125000 elements could be problematic. And you also want to leave room for other auto variables.

Really big arrays should not be allocated on the stack.

You could try allocating it in the heap instead:

```
long long *ways = calloc(max+1, sizeof *ways);
if (ways == NULL) {
    // allocation failed!!
}
// Do stuff.
free(ways);
```

Comment: Minor idea: `long long *ways = calloc(max+1, sizeof *ways);` style instead.  IMO, easier to code and maintain.

Comment: @chux Agreed! That way there is one less place to change if you want to change the type the array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot spot the difference between these two.

Comment: @Chandan I have updated my answer. `sizeof *ways` is better than `sizeof (long long)`.

Comment: It will use the same amount of memory, but from the heap instead of from the stack.